# Updating a MySQL table, but only querying the maximum value

Tags: mysql, drupal, group-by, sql-update, max

I've got a Drupal install with the events module installed. I've written a short plugin that searches for all events where the end date has passed and makes then not live. It's basically an SQL query like so:

```
UPDATE node LEFT JOIN content_field_dates on node.nid = content_field_dates.nid SET node.status = 0 WHERE node.type = 'event' AND field_dates_value2 < NOW() AND node.status = 1
```

However, some events may have multiple dates, and this query sets the status to 0 even if one date has passed and some dates are still in the future. I've managed to do a `SELECT` query only queries the `MAX()` date like so:

```
SELECT * FROM node LEFT JOIN content_field_dates on node.nid = content_field_dates.nid WHERE node.type = 'event' AND field_dates_value2 < NOW() GROUP BY field_dates_value2 HAVING field_dates_value2 = MAX(field_dates_value2)
```

but I have no idea how this would translate to an `UPDATE` query as I can't use `GROUP BY`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the `max` into an inline view and then join against that. Note that since you have a predicate on the `content_field_dates` table you will not gain anything by performing a `LEFT JOIN` onto it.

Anyway, this should hopefully get you what you want:

```
UPDATE node n
join (
select nid,max(field_dates_value2) as maxDate
from content_field_dates
group by nid
) t on n.nid = t.nid
SET n.status = 0 
where t.maxDate < now() and n.status = 1;
```